# Wordpress if is page then initMap google map coordinates

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I have a wordpress site with a bunch of contact pages and I would like to initMap at certain coordinates based on the page.

The google maps are working all fine without it but my conditional code doesn't seem work and I am getting 500 status errors. Thanks

```
var initLat; //originally var initLat = xxx;
var initLng; //originally var initLng = xxx;
<?php
var $initLag;
var $initLng;
if(is_page("page-1")){
  $initLag = -24;
  $initLng = 143;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-2")){
  $initLat = -13;
  $initLng = 163;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-3")){
  $initLat = -54;
  $initLng = 43;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-4")){
  $initLat = 14;
  $initLng = 23;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif is_page("page-5")){
  $initLat = 5;
  $initLng = 66;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-6")){
  $initLat = 9;
  $initLng = 111;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-7")){
  $initLat = -34;
  $initLng = 66;?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php } elseif(is_page("page-8")){
  $initLat = 48.343816,
  $initLng = 16.384727?>
  initLat = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
  initLng = "<?php echo $initLag  ?>";
<?php }?>

function initMap(){
    var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(initLat, initLng),
    //rest of code
    ...
```

Comment: if u used static lat-lng then why first store that in php variable and used in javascript. assign js variable initLat = -13 directly

Comment: also debug your code and alert(initLat) and check, also debug your is_page() return value once and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your code seems you missed  the semicolon at the end of the echo

```
 "<?php echo $initLag .";" ;  ?>";
```

but You could use a simple way using switch  and assign the code directly with echo

assuming your page name is stored in $my_page

```
    var initLat; //originally var initLat = xxx;
    var initLng; //originally var initLng = xxx;
    <?php


      switch($my_page){
        case  'page-1';
          echo " initLat = -24; 
          ";
          echo " initLng = 143;
          ";
        break;
        case  'page-1';
          echo " initLat = -13; 
          ";
          echo " initLng = 163;
          ";
        break;


      }

    ?>


    function initMap(){
        var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(initLat, initLng),
        //rest of code
        ...
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the suggestion. I have made `$my_page = is_page();` before the switch statement. Maps is showing up however only the first case is working on all pages.. not sure what is wrong exactly?

Comment: Never mind I made the statement `$my_page = basename(get_permalink());switch($my_page){ ...`